# how to use sbt shell to try small sbt expressions

Tags: sbt

like scala shell, does sbt shell provides a way to play around with sbt code

- i.e. can I use sbt shell to create temporary tasks/settings and play with them
- e.g. redefine existing definitions(in build.sbt) on sbt shell

I see set and eval commands but not sure how can I use sbt shell for testing some small sbt expression. I see that there session command as well.

Please provide a overview on how to try sbt shell as an interpreter of sbt expressions

Comment: not sure who down voted the question and why?
what's wrong with my question....don't understand the -ve voting

Answer (score 0):

You can try using consoleProject that allows you to eval settings and tasks and generally explore around your build. Its not the exact same thing that you're asking but maybe offers similar functionality?

[Console Project Docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Console-Project.html)

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks for your reply. Seems to be what I am looking for :)

Can you please vote up the question as someone somehow down voted the question.